# canvas or requestAnimationFrame is slow in mobile

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe, mobile-browser

I have a problem in mobile browsers.
I maked a **canvas chart** without any js library or frameworks, but its animations is very very slow in mobile

I use this function for requestAnimationFrame:

```
(function () {
var lastTime = 0;
var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
}

if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) window.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
    var currTime = new Date().getTime();
    var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
    var id = window.setTimeout(function () {
            callback(currTime + timeToCall);
        },
        timeToCall);
    lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
    return id;
};

if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) window.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
    clearTimeout(id);
};
}());

requestAnimationFrame(myFunc);

function myFunc(){
    //any code
    .
    .
    requestAnimationFrame(myFunc);
})
```

What should I do?

Comment: it's slow because canvas is slow, `requestAnimationFrame` has little/nothing to do with it

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I see mr.doob works in my mobile phone and they are very smooth, why not my chart like them? :(

Comment: Mr. doob is using webgl with three.js, I'm betting you're not. WebGL is going to be orders of magnitude faster than raw pixel manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you didn't post the *relevant* code. How you are drawing to the canvas is almost certainly your problem. There are a few tips for making that better:

- Draw to an offscreen canvas and copy the image data over all at once.
- Combine the above with multiple canvases, only draw layers that have changed e.g. your graph layer may have changed but not the labels/legend.
- Draw to a smaller canvas and scale it up.

To be honest though, mobile browsers are way, way slower than their desktop counterparts for a variety of reasons (heat and power consumption being two rather large ones). If you want smooth animations you will have to either write some high-performance rendering code (likely in WebGL) or use someone elses (e.g. pixi.js).